# Save tensorflow 2.0 model and use them in opencv 4

Tags: opencv, tensorflow

I currently code my models with tensorflow 2.0 and I want to run them with opencv 4 (I want to compare performance). But I can't find a way to convert my tensorflow model for opencv.

For running in opencv I want to use:

`cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('saved_model.pb', 'saved_model.pbtxt')`

but when I save my model with:

`model.save('./')`

I obtain this files:

*saved_model.pb* | *variables/variables.index* | *variables/variables.data-00000-of-00002* |*variables/variables.data-00001-of-00002*

I have a my .pb but not my .pbtxt. How it is possible to write this file ? According to opencv documentation this file is the text graph definition. I already try to write a .pbtxt with
`model.to_json()`
but it didn't work :/

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Tanguy

Answer (score 0):

> Additionally, OpenCV requires an extra configuration file based on the
>   .pb, the  .pbtxt. It is possible to import your own models and
>   generate your own .pbtxt files by using one of the following files
>   from the OpenCV Github repository...

Here is a link to tutorial: https://jeanvitor.com/tensorflow-object-detecion-opencv/
Haven't tried it myself, but seems legit.
For example `tf_text_graph_ssd.py` does job done.

Comment: Your link is for object-detection api tensorflow models only, here is another tutorial for the same: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API I have used this method and it works, but only for select object detection models.  Conversion instructions and working models are in the link I shared. The OP is creating custom models, I haven't seen anyway to use opencv with custom defined models.

Comment: @shortcipher3, you are right, but I thought that the main problem is lack of ``.pbtxt``.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but yes my problem is the lack of .pbtxt :/

Comment: @TanguyHardelin, so did you figure out how to generate it using the script from the link I sent?

Comment: Yes I tried but your script seem work only with ssd / rcnn. I want do my test with a RESNet model (for compare if opencv do some good optimizations). 
Is it possible to write a generic script for convert all types of models ?

Comment: I don't think so. However if you only want to compare performance, you can find RESNet retrained models in the web, there are some with already generated pbtxt files.